# How do I fill up mask holes in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, mask

I'm using a clothing dataset for some tasks and I need to create a black and white mask of the clothing items. I'm using this code to achieve the below:

```
img = cv2.imread(filepath, 0)
#img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,250,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(new_dir_path, filename), th3)
```

Here's an example of what I have so far:

[image: original correct] [image: correct]

**and I'm getting erroneous ones like these**

[image: original]
[image: errorneous]

How can I fill out the holes appropriately so I can get a solid appearance like the first pair?

** ****EDIT**** **

I also tried employing edge detection with the code below:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=100, threshold2=200) # Canny Edge Detection
```

**and I get this for this**

[image: problem]

The problem is it's a very hit and miss. For certain cases I get correct edges, and for others I don't. Also how would I be able to fill out the wholes if the edges are complex like above?

Comment: You could rather find the edge map and  draw the largest contour

Comment: Edited the above question. I still have some problems with edge detection and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: From the thresholded mask, just use morphology close to close up holes. Use a kernel whose diameter will be about the size of the holes or larger.

Comment: Is there always pure white background? Use Sobel magnitude threshold for edge detection. Or threshold white color and invert the mask.

Comment: there is always pure white background, the problem is that the edges aren't being smoothly detected since there may be other clothes that are pure white too , I'm trying to play around with the Canny parameters but I have no luck yet

Comment: @mesllo Try out different techniques like Sobel mentioned above or Difference of Gaussians.

Comment: Sobel with a very low theshold should work. If cloth and background are pure white it's impossible for aby simple algorithm to segment that. But typically there is at least a very thin edge between pure white background and pure white foreground, a result of the surface normals and lighting.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know the background will always be white, I think you can do something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
filepath = 'dress.png'
img = cv2.imread(filepath)

# find the mask
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# set some absolute values for the threshold, since we know the background will always be white
_, mask = cv2.threshold(img_gray,244,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

# find the largest contour 
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_inv, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_contour = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[0]

# draw the largest contour to fill in the holes in the mask
final_result = np.ones(img.shape[:2]) # create a blank canvas to draw the final result
final_result = cv2.drawContours(final_result, [largest_contour], -1, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

# show results
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('final_result', final_result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: final result]

Comment: Can you share the output as well?

Comment: @JeruLuke, I just updated my answer with the output image.

Comment: result is as expected

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately the result I get from this code is a black picture. I am assuming final_result is the solution, of course. The mask renders me the middle image of your solution.

Comment: @mesllo, that is very odd. I tried it again just now, and it works for me, and it seems to work for the other commenter too. I'm not sure what might be causing the issue you are seeing. You might experiment with different ways of drawing the contours, e.g. draw them on to an existing image or convert the white canvas to color first before drawing.